# How to remove an element from a separate JSON file using just that elements ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, postman

So I'm new to JS and none of the solutions I have found online have worked for me. I am creating a backend for a todolist, and I want to add the app.delete functionality so I can delete items from the list.

Here is the code in my separate json file:

```
    [{"id":1,"name":"item 1","complete":true},{"id":2,"name":"Walk the dog","complete":false},{"id":3,"name":"Go shopping","complete":false}]
```

Here is what I tried, but to be honest I just wrote whatever came to mind for this:

```
    app.delete('/todo/:id/delete', (request, response) => {
    const id = request.params.id

    const findTodobyID = (todos, id) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++){
            if(todos[i].id === parseInt(id)){
                return i 
            }
        }
        return -1
    }  
    fs.readFile('./store/todos.json', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            return response.status(500).send('Sorry, something went wrong.')
        }

        let todos = JSON.parse(data)
        const todoIndex = findTodobyID(todos, id)

        if (todoIndex === -1) {
            return response.status(404).send('Sorry, ID not found')
        }

        todos[todoIndex].complete = true

        fs.writeFile('./store/todos.json', JSON.delete(todos), () => {
            return response.json({'status': 'Deleted ID' + id})
        })
    })
})
```

This is the error I get when I run it in Postman:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot DELETE /todos/3/delete</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI there's a built-in method `Array.prototype.findIndex` that does what your `findTodobyID` function does.

Comment: There's no point in setting the `complete` property if you're deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the `todoIndex`th element from an array:

```
todos.splice(todoIndex, 1);
```

Also before writing it, you should use:

```
JSON.stringify(todos);
```

Instead of `JSON.delete(todos)`.